# NLog argument substitution

Tags: nlog

```
Logger.Trace("expensive message:{0}",calcResult());
```

the method `calcResult()` is executed even if the logging level is higher then Trace. 
What is the best/most elegant approach to avoid the calling of the method?

Thank you
(using NLog 4.4.12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
Logger.Trace("expensive message:{0}", () => calcResult());
```

Or something like this:

```
if (Logger.IsTraceEnabled)
    Logger.Trace("expensive message:{0}", calcResult());
```